# Build error Team City .NET Core with .NET libraries reference

Tags: deployment, msbuild, asp.net-core, teamcity

I'm struggling to find out what is the problem building a .NET Core project with csproj references using Team City, I'm actually newbie related team city process but I've read another similar issues but none of the workarounds works for me.
This is the message Team City shows:

```
error NU1001: The dependency Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore >= 1.0.0 could not be resolved. 
•   C:\BuildAgent\work\1e2a73a15b18c502\ProjectFolder\ProjectCore\project.json(4, 39): error NU1001: The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc >= 1.0.1 could not be resolved. 
•   C:\BuildAgent\work\1e2a73a15b18c502\ProjectFolder\ProjectCore\project.json(11, 50): error NU1001: The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel >= 1.0.1 could not be resolved. 
•   C:\BuildAgent\work\1e2a73a15b18c502\ProjectFolder\ProjectCore\project.json(13, 64): error NU1001: The dependency Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions >= 1.0.0 could not be resolved. 
•   C:\BuildAgent\work\1e2a73a15b18c502\ProjectFolder\ProjectCore\project.json(14, 54): error NU1001: The dependency Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json >= 1.0.0 could not be resolved. 
•   C:\BuildAgent\work\1e2a73a15b18c502\ProjectFolder\ProjectCore\project.json(16, 51): error NU1001: The dependency Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console >= 1.0.0 could not be resolved. 
•   C:\BuildAgent\work\1e2a73a15b18c502\ProjectFolder\ProjectCore\project.json(17, 49): error NU1001: The dependency Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug >= 1.0.0 could not be resolved. 
•   C:\BuildAgent\work\1e2a73a15b18c502\ProjectFolder\ProjectCore\project.json(18, 67): error NU1001: The dependency Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions >= 1.0.0 could not be resolved. 
•   C:\BuildAgent\work\1e2a73a15b18c502\ProjectFolder\ProjectCore\project.json(24, 43): error NU1001: The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session >= 1.0.0 could not be resolved. 
•   C:\BuildAgent\work\1e2a73a15b18c502\ProjectFolder\ProjectCore\project.json(25, 34): error NU1001: The dependency Swashbuckle >= 6.0.0-beta901 could not be resolved. 
•   C:\BuildAgent\work\1e2a73a15b18c502\ProjectFolder\ProjectCore\project.json(27, 25): error NU1001: The dependency ***.Utilities - .net 4.5.0 project*** could not be resolved. 
•   C:\BuildAgent\work\1e2a73a15b18c502\ProjectFolder\ProjectCore\project.json(30, 24): error NU1001: The dependency ***.Data - .net 4.5.2 project *** could not be resolved. 
•   C:\BuildAgent\work\1e2a73a15b18c502\ProjectFolder\ProjectCore\project.json(33, 28): error NU1001: The dependency ***.Domain - .net 4.5.2 project*** could not be resolved.
```

This is my project.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "FluentNHibernate": "2.0.3",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client": "5.2.3",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session": "1.0.0",
    "Swashbuckle": "6.0.0-beta901"

  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net452": {
      "dependencies": {
        "***.Utilities": {
          "target": "project"
        },
        "***.Data": {
          "target": "project"
        },
        "***.Domain": {
          "target": "project"
        }
      }
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Could someone help me with this? I'm out of ideas of what could be the problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This looks like the build server can't communicate with the NuGet source.  Does the build server have internet access?  Is it using the default NuGet source or do you have a custom NuGet source defined for the solution?

Comment: We have another projects inside the same solution, all of them pure .NET...this new project is .NET Core and is the only one giving error during the build process, As far as I know, we are using the default NuGet package...I'm really stuck in this process and probably I'll spend next days just trying to figure out how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I've just run across a similar issue for a .NET Core Project referencing the full .NET Framework 4.6.1.

First of all, check whether the correct .NET core version is installed on your build server.
Actual .NET Core versions can be found [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core#/lts).

Then check the NuGet.exe version, and upgrade it ot 3.5.0 if needed.

Then, as per this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42402586/6011874), download and install the correct .NET Framework target profile and restart both the TeamCity Agent and Server services. *(This step was causing my build failures)*

Finally, rebuild your solution. TeamCity should successfully restore the packages and build the solution.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually I solved my problem adding a build step to execute the Nuget `restore` command "manually". At the time I've posted, this was the only way to make it work. Thanks!